# Assigning column value based on highest value across multiple columns and value label in another column

Tags: r

I need help with a function to assign value in the "ans" column which represents the highest value between (c1l,c2l,c3l)- these are the numeric values corresponding to their character value in c1,c2,c3. For row 1 in "ans", value "B" was assigned from column c2 in "ans" because 13 is the highest value across c1l,c2l,c3l while c2l represents the value label in c2 ("B"). If all the other columns value were NA, then col "ans" will take the only value between c1l,c2l,c3l and assign character value from c1,c2,c3 to ans.  So the logic for this function would be similar to something like this:

condition 1:
if max between c1l,c2l,c3l then ans = c(i) with i between cols c1-c3

condition 2:
if c1l,c2l,c3l all NA then ans=c1

Thanks!

```
c1<-c("A","B","NA","B")
c2<-c("B","C","D","A")
c3<-c("C","A","C","C")
c1l<-c(10,12,NA,NA)
c2l<-c(13,11,NA,NA)
c3l<-c(9,10,5,NA)
ans<-c("B","A","C","B")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `max.col` :

```
df <- data.frame(c1, c2, c3, c1l, c2l, c3l)
#get the value columns 
cols <- grep('c\\d+l', names(df))
#Replace NA with 0 and get the max value in each row
cols_index <- max.col(replace(df[cols], is.na(df[cols]), 0))
#If all the values are NA in a row replace it with NA
cols_index[rowSums(!is.na(df[cols]), na.rm = TRUE) == 0] <- NA
#get the corresponding label column creating a row/column matrix
df$ans <- df[-cols][cbind(1:nrow(df), cols_index)]
df$ans
#[1] "B" "B" "C" NA
```

To check if there is only one value in one of `c1`, `c2` , `c3`, we can do

```
inds <- rowSums(!is.na(df[is.na(df$ans), -cols])) == 1
if(any(inds)) df$ans[inds] <- sapply(inds, function(x) 
                                na.omit(unlist(df[x, -cols])))
```

Comment: Thanks, Ronak. I have a slight modification need to make. If c1l-c3l had no values, while only c1 had a value, e.g."A" but c2 and c3 where "NA", then col ans will grab "A" for that row. Currently, it shows NA. Thanks again!

Comment: @DHR and what if c1l-c3l had no values while c1 and c2 has some value which value to select?

Comment: if c1 and c2 had both values to select from then ans=NA, same for c3. The only exception case as I mentioned was there that no numeric values in cl1-3 but either c1 or c2 or c3 has a single value without the need to select. So if no values were in cl1-3 and only 1 value is available between c1-3, then ans is assigned value according to c1-3.  In my original dataset. c1,c2,c3 where variables separated from strings e.g. ("country1/country2/country3", "country1/country4") and c1l-c3l were country related metric.

Comment: Thanks Ronak. I edited the question to reflect the additional condition. However, I think I haven't explained myself clearly earlier. Please see "condition 2" of the post and would appreciate if you could adjust the code so NA in ans would be replaced by c1 when c1l-c3l were all NA . Thanks!